# Measuring Execution Time For Multithreaded Java Application

Tags: java, multithreading

I've searched about measuring execution time for Java application and I get this code:

```
long start= System.currentTimeMillis();
//TODO
long stop= System.currentTimeMillis();
```

Difference between start and stop gives me the execution time.

NOTE: I'm aware of this is not the EXACT execution time. I just need the time for comparison between multithread and single thread applications.

What if I change my code like this:

```
long start= System.currentTimeMillis();
//something...
Thread t1= new Thread(new blabla(0, 10), "T - 1");
t1.start();
Thread t2= new Thread(new blabla(10, 20), "T - 2");
t2.start();
//Consider I've 10 threads like this
//something more
long stop = System.currentTimeMillis();
```

10 thread executes. Doesn't matter what they do. Let's say they're randomly filling up a 2D array.

Now, stop - start gives me the "whole" execution time? Or do I have to measure threads by themselves?

Comment: which version of Java do you use?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your multithreaded example won't work the way you intend it to be, because when you call `start()` on a thread it will run concurrently. So what basically happens is you start all 10 threads and it is possible that none of them actually started its work before you called

```
long stop = System.currentTimeMillis();
```

If you want to measure the full runtime it takes for your tasks to complete you have to wait for all threads to finish first, which you could do like this:

```
long start = System.currentTimeMillis();

List<Thread> threads = new ArrayList<>();

for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
    Thread t = new Thread(new blabla(i * 10, (i + 1) * 10), "T - " + (i + 1));
    t.start();
    threads.add(t);
}

// and now wait for all of them to complete
for (Thread t : threads) {
    t.join();
}

long stop = System.currentTimeMillis();
```

Note that this only works if your threads terminate after execution (i.e. your `blabla` runnable does not run in an endless loop or something).

Alternatively you could use an ExecutorService (e.g. `Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10)`, see [the Java API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html)) that you could submit tasks to and wait for the termination of all tasks.

Comment: I was pretty sure that my 1-5 ms results are wrong. Also, eclipse console writes - for example - 5 ms. But terminate button was still available. Threads were working, of course. Now I tried your method and results make sense. Of course I'm not 100% of measuring but even if I tweak thread count, I see differences. Thanks.

Comment: There is another way you could measure the runtime of your application, but it would only work if you want to measure the performance in isolation, i.e. with a dedicated `main()` method: upon start of main you save the start time and then you register a shutdown hook via `System.getRuntime().addShutdownHook()`. It gets called when the JVM terminates and there you could take the time again and print out the runtime by subtracting the start time.

Answer (score 0):

```
    final long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

    // do multi threaded work

    Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread(() -> {
        System.out.println("Shutdown Hook is running !");
        final long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.println("Calculated in: " + (endTime - startTime) / 1000 + " seconds" );
    }));
```