# How to Measure execution time for a multi threaded task in java

Tags: java, concurrency, java.util.concurrent

I have a method which makes lets say 100k http calls to an API, for that reason I am making the http calls concurrently to avoid http bottleneck. But I would also like to time the whole method without blocking any threads.

```java
        ExecutorService service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(500);
        for (int i = 0; i < 100_000; i++) {
            int finalI = i;
            Runnable runnable = () -> {
                // My http call goes here....
            };
            service.submit(runnable);
        }
```

Comment: Making HTTP calls concurrently to the same server won't save you much. There is only one network, and it isn't concurrent. And the only 'calculation' required is end time minus start time. This is really measurement, not calculation.

Comment: Relevant question and answers: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37172989/measuring-execution-time-for-multithreaded-java-application

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wish to get a rough idea of the time the whole set of operations takes then use `shutdown` then `awaitTermination` to wait for the executor service to finish all of the submitted tasks. Here is a simple example:

```
long start= System.nanoTime();
ExecutorService exec = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(100);
try {
    for (int i = 0; i < 100_000; i++) {
        final int x = i;
        Runnable runnable = () -> System.out.println(x);
        exec.submit(runnable);
    }
} finally {
    exec.shutdown();
    exec.awaitTermination(365, TimeUnit.DAYS);
}
long elapsed = System.nanoTime() - start;
System.out.println("Elapsed millisec "+TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS.toMillis(elapsed));
```

It's not a good idea to put `System.out.println` or other logging inside the tasks as then you are only timing your console I/O, and not getting an estimate of how quick your processing is.

As in the comments, using multi-thread access to same set of servers / resource / disk can make overall elapsed time get longer or cause issues elsewhere.

From JDK19 the `ExecutorService` is `AutoCloseable` so you can simplify the try block and remove the finally:

```
try (ExecutorService exec = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(100)) {
     ...
}
```